# NSUserDefaults registerDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm registering defaults in AppDelegate:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let registrationDictionary = [kSelectedBitrate: 128 as NSNumber, kSelectedCodec: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC as NSNumber]
        defaults.registerDefaults(registrationDictionary)
        defaults.synchronize()
```

However, when I read it later in view controller, both integer values are 0:

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let bitrate = defaults.integerForKey(kSelectedBitrate)
    println(bitrate)
    let codec = defaults.integerForKey(kSelectedCodec)
    println(codec)
    println(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)
```

Console log

```
0
0
1633772320
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Try replacing the 'as NSNumber' by 'as Int'

Comment: @TheTom It's the same result.

Comment: the code works for me. unless (it's silly) somehow the `kSelectedBitrate` and `kSelectedCodec` are different in both cases.

Comment: @rakeshbs So you get 128 printed in console? Can you please tell me your Xcode version? (Mine is 6.1.1)

Comment: mine is also `6.1.1` I set it in AppDelegate and called it in my viewController `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: where are you calling it in the viewController? It doesn't work inside the `initWithCoder` function of the firstViewController.

Comment: @rakeshbs Well, I call it also right after setting, to check and have same 0 results.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was that controller was loading before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`.

So, I duplicated code to `init` method of the controller, and problem is solved.